# How can we do weekly range group in Firebird?

Tags: sql, group-by, firebird

I have problem with some script in Firebird. I want to put my date in week category that should be start from Saturday, but unfortunately the last day couldn't put in correct position

```
SELECT
    dateadd(week, DATEDIFF(week, date '1-1-1900', cast(s.NNDate as date)),date '1-6-1900') AS Week_Clm,
    cast(s.NNDate as date), Menge
FROM
(
    SELECT cast(New_DATUM AS date) AS NNDate, sum(LGL_MENGE) AS Menge
    FROM View_LAGERLOG
    WHERE (  LGL_REFNUMMER = '0' OR
             LGL_REFNUMMER = '1' OR
             LGL_REFNUMMER = '2' OR
             LGL_REFNUMMER = '3' OR
             LGL_REFNUMMER = '4')
    GROUP BY cast(New_DATUM as date)
) s
```

[image: [enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eljHT.png)

Comment: Please describe the problem in more detail. What are you trying to do, and what is the problem?

Comment: Hi I have a table with Columns
First Column called "menge"(In Germany and Equal "amount")
Second Column Called "New_DATUM" (In Germany and Equal "Date")
for every amount we have one date 
-------------------
in First SELECT I did a Group on "New_DATUM" or Date and I sum all amount that we have in same date 
-------------------

Comment: Hi I have a table with Columns
First Column called "menge"(In Germany and Equal "amount")
Second Column Called "New_DATUM" (In Germany and Equal "Date")
for every amount we have one date 
-
in First SELECT I did a Group on "New_DATUM" or Date and I sum all amount that we have in same date 
--
in Second SELECT I want to show  "New_DATUM" belong to witch week (Week_CLM) and I want to start my week from Saturday
--
but I have  problem if you see for example : in Week_CLM we have 18/06/206 but for this week in CAST column 19/06/2016
-
19/06/2016 should be for next week

Comment: You should **edit** your question with extra details, not post them as comments. However, please give some more thought before editing your question, because I don't understand what you are trying to say with the last two comments you posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at extract function in Firebird. Tested with Firebird 3.0:

```sql
select
  extract (year from current_date) as dyear,
  extract (week from current_date) as dweek
from rdb$database
```

You may concatenate them as one field for later data management.